# XML with Schema not validating and giving me "content of element declaration must match"

Tags: xml, validation, schema

I have been trying to figure out why this .xsd and .xml are not validating. I get an error on line 17, column 57 that says

> "Content of element declaration must match (annotation?, (simpleType |
>   complexType)?, (unique| key keyref)*)

The odd thing is that if I remove line 17 in both the .xsd and the .xml the error still pops up in the same spot for some reason.

Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cursos xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="reto4MarcasGrupo1Schema.xsd">
        <curso codigoCurso="AA2000">
          <nombreCurso>Manejo Ofimatica</nombreCurso>
          <numPlazas>20</numPlazas>
          <numHoras horario="diurno">300</numHoras>
          <fechaInicio>18-2-2018</fechaInicio>
          <fechaFin> 30-3-2018</fechaFin>
          <objetivos>Los objetivos de este curso es que las personas tengan un manejo basico de apliaciones de ofimatica</objetivos>
          <entidadColaboradora nombreEntidad="H"/>
          <diaSemana>L</diaSemana>
          <cuotas tipoCuotas="subvencionado100"/>
          <equipamiento>Ordeandores basicos</equipamiento>
          <dirigidoA tipoDirigido="desempleadosYempleados"/>
          <estado tipoEstado="aRealizar"/>
          <programa>
              <tema codigoTema="AAT001">
                <tituloTema>Introduccion</tituloTema>
                <impartidor>Ron Weasly</impartidor>
              </tema>
              <tema codigoTema="AAT002">
                <tituloTema>Introduccion</tituloTema>
                <impartidor>Jon Nieve</impartidor>
              </tema>
          </programa>
        </curso>
</cursos>
```

It's an excersice to organice classes in different grades.

And here is my Schema:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="cursos" type="tipoCursos"/>

  <xs:complexType name="tipoCursos">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="curso" type="tipoCurso" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="tipoCurso">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="nombreCurso" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="numPlazas" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
      <xs:element name="numHoras" type="tipoNumHoras"/>
      <xs:element name="fechaInicio" type="xs:date"/>
      <xs:element name="objetivos" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="entidadColaboradora" type="tipoEntidadColaboradora"/>
      <xs:element name="diaSemana" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="cuotas" type="cuotaTipo"/>
      <xs:element name="equipamiento" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="dirigidoA" type="tipoDirigido"/>
      <xs:element name="estado" type="estadoTipo"/>
      <xs:element name="programa" type="tipoPrograma"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="codigoCurso" type="xs:ID"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="tipoPrograma">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="tema" type="tipoTema" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="tipoTema">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="tituloTema" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="impartidor" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="codigoTema" type="xs:ID"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="tipoNumHoras">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="numHoras" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="horario" type="tipoHorario"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="cuotaTipo">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="subvencionado100"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="subvencionParcial"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="sinSubvencion"/>
      </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="estadoTipo">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="aplazado"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="realizado"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="aRealizar"/>
      </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="tipoDirigido">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="desempleadosYempleados"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="preferiblementeEmpleados"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="segunCursos"/>
      </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>


  <xs:simpleType name="tipoEntidadColaboradora">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="H"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="HC"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="S"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="I"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="D"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="E"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="J"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="M"/>
      </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="tipoHorario">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="diurno"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="nocturno"/>
      </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Please mark the line in XSD where the error is reported. Otherwise your force us to count lines in your code snippets.

Comment: Your schema is invalid. Please fix the schema in the question. The type `tipoHorario` is not defined in the XSD.

Comment: Your XML is invalid because you have a `codigoCurso` attribute on the `curso` element. Your schema defines that on the `cursos` element.

Comment: Matt is right. You can use online tools like https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-xsd-validator if your data is not sensitive

Comment: You've also defined your `tipoNumHoras` so that your XML sample `numHoras` element is invalid.

Comment: @MattJones I added the type tipoHorario and have changed the codigoCurso atribute from cursos to curso and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @lexicore I've added the a comment on the line in the xsd where it gives me the error.

Comment: You still have a `codigoCurso` attribute on the `curso` element and your schema still defines it as being on the `tipoCursos` type, not on the `tipoCurso` type.

Comment: It edited it because it didn't save for some reason

Comment: @Ariwake Sorry, I somehow fail to see your comment in the schema. In the edits I see it's about the `fechaInicio` but somehow your comment is missing now.

Comment: @Ariwake With the schema as given in the question, I cannot reproduce the problem you are reporting. I've compiled your schema with JAXB XJC which is quite strict about validating schemas - without any problems.

Comment: @Ariwake Even your XML *almost* validates against the XSD, there is only one problem with `numHoras` which is clear (`tipoNumHoras` should be a complex type with simple content and an attribute, not a complex type).

Comment: @Ariwake So I'm inclined to vote to close as the problem cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is saying that a schema is invalid. But I don't think it's referring to the schema that you've shown us, because that one is fine. So I think you need to tell us more about exactly what you are doing: for example which schema processor you are using, and how you are invoking it. (Perhaps it's the schema referenced in the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute that's the culprit?)

Your instance document is not valid against the schema. Here are the errors as reported by Saxon:

```
Validation error on line 6 column 50 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: The content model for element <numHoras> does not allow character content
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cvc-complex-type clause 2.3
Validation error on line 6 column 36 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: In content of element <numHoras>: Empty content is not allowed. Expected <numHoras>. 
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cvc-complex-type clause 2.4
Validation error on line 7 column 22 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: The content "18-2-2018" of element <fechaInicio> does not match the required
  simple type. Invalid date "18-2-2018" (Year is less than four digits)
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#cvc-datatype-valid clause 1
Validation error on line 8 column 19 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: In content of element <curso>: The content model does not allow element
  <fechaFin> to appear immediately after element <fechaInicio>. Expected <objetivos>. 
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cvc-complex-type clause 2.4
Validation error on line 10 column 49 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: Attribute @nombreEntidad is not allowed on element <entidadColaboradora>
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cvc-complex-type clause 3
Validation error on line 10 column 49 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: The content "" of element <entidadColaboradora> does not match the required
  simple type. Value "" contravenes the enumeration facet "D, E, HC, M, H, I, J, S" of the
  type tipoEntidadColaboradora
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#cvc-datatype-valid clause 1
Validation error on line 12 column 48 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: Attribute @tipoCuotas is not allowed on element <cuotas>
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cvc-complex-type clause 3
Validation error on line 12 column 48 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: The content "" of element <cuotas> does not match the required simple type.
  Value "" contravenes the enumeration facet "subvencionado100, subvencionPa..." of the type cuotaTipo
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#cvc-datatype-valid clause 1
Validation error on line 14 column 59 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: Attribute @tipoDirigido is not allowed on element <dirigidoA>
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cvc-complex-type clause 3
Validation error on line 14 column 59 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: The content "" of element <dirigidoA> does not match the required simple type.
  Value "" contravenes the enumeration facet "preferiblementeEmpleados, segu..." of the type
  tipoDirigido
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#cvc-datatype-valid clause 1
Validation error on line 15 column 41 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: Attribute @tipoEstado is not allowed on element <estado>
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cvc-complex-type clause 3
Validation error on line 15 column 41 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: The content "" of element <estado> does not match the required simple type.
  Value "" contravenes the enumeration facet "realizado, aRealizar, aplazado" of the type estadoTipo
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#cvc-datatype-valid clause 1
Validation error on line 27 column 10 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: Twelve validation errors were reported
Validation of file test.xml completed: errors found
```

But this has nothing to do with the error that you've posted.

Comment: It turns out that this error and the one I was getting are pretty much the same. I had declared simpleTypes with attributes in them which caused an error during validation as you cannot do this. What I did was change the XML for every empty element and remove the attributes from them as well placing the value that I specified in the XSD inside said element. I'll update the main topic to show my solution. Thanks!!